# How to use filter(), map() to work with values fo an array? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

My task is:

> Implement the function duplicateStudents(), which gets the variable
> "students" and filters for students with the same matriculation
> number. Firstly, project all elements in students by matriculation
> number. After that you can filter for duplicates relatively easily. At
> the end project using the following format: { matrikelnummer:
> (matrikelnummer), students: [ (students[i], students[j], ... ) ] }.
>
> Implement the invalidGrades() function, which gets the variable "grades"
> and filters for possibly incorrect notes. For example, in order to
> keep a manual check as low as possible, the function should determine
> for which matriculation numbers several grades were transmitted for
> the same course. Example: For matriculation number X, a 2. 7 and a 2.
> 3 were transmitted for course Y. However, the function would also take
> into account the valid case, i. e. for matriculation number X, once a
> 5,0 and once a 2,3 were transmitted for course Y.
>
> In this task you should only use map(), reduce(), and filter(). Do not
> implement for-loops.

```
function duplicateStudents(students) {
  return students
    // TODO: implement me
}

function invalidGrades(grades) {
  return grades
    .map((s) => {
      // TODO: implement me

      return {
        matrikelnummer: -1/* put something here */,
        grades: []/* put something here */,
      };
    })
    .filter((e) => e.grades.length > 0)
}
```

The variables students and grades I have in a separate file. I know it might be helpful to upload the files too, but one is 1000 lines long, the other 500. That’s why I’m not uploading them. But I hope it is possible to do the task without the values. It is important to say that the values are represented as an array[image]

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example of using reduce on `duplicateStudents`, that's not returning the expected format but you could go from there.

```js
const duplicateStudents = (students) => {
  const grouping = students.reduce((previous, current) => {
    if (previous[current.matrikelnummer]) previous[current.matrikelnummer].push(current); // add student if matrikelnummer already exist
    else previous[current.matrikelnummer] = [current];
    return previous;
  }, {});

  console.log(grouping);
  
  return //you could process `grouping` to the expected format in here
};
```

here's preferences for you:

- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)